# Unable to use USB as a storage device due to balenaetcher

Tags: usb, partition-recovery, dualboot

I tried to flash a kali linux iso disk onto my USB using 'balena etcher'. I did this thinking that I would still be able to use my USB as a storage device afterwards but apparently not.

I am using a MacOS Big sur and am using an Intenso USB stick.

I can boot into kali linux which was my intended purpose but I am unable to use my USB stick as a storage device anymore as it appears ***greyed out*** in 'Disk Utility'. I tried erasing it but it came up with this error message:

```
Couldn’t modify partition map. : (-69874)
```

I have searched for a long time on the internet but have found no solutions that work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a USB disk starts having too many errors, it becomes read-only.
It is possibly what happened to your disk.

If the disk supports SMART, you could verify its status this way.
Add the SMART info to your post if you want our opinion.

You could try to reformat the disk by a command such as:

```
diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 UNTITLED MBRFormat /dev/diskN
```

Once the erase is finished, you could again try to see if it is now
writable. If not, then the disk may be broken.

For more information, see
[Etcher broke my USB stick … or did it?](https://www.balena.io/blog/did-etcher-break-my-usb-sd-card/)

Comment: I tried the command but with a volume before. I tried it with the disk now and it works.